# Disposing of static resource ViewModels

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a simple ViewModel

```
    public class TestViewModel : ViewModelBase, IDisposable
    {

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<string>(this, MessageHandling);
    }

    public void MessageHandling(string message)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(message);
    }
    public override void Cleanup()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Unregister(this);
        base.Cleanup();
    }
    }
```

And i use it in my XAML like this:

```
   <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <vm:TestViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"></vm:TestViewModel>
    </ResourceDictionary>
   </Window.Resources>
   <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}">
   </Grid>
```

Can anyone help we with disposing of this ViewModel, by disposing i mean on which event should i subscribe to call VM method cleanup? Because if I don't do Cleanup the ViewModel remains in memory and still handles messages.
I hope i explained it properly :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: It appears that you are using `MVVM Light Toolkit`, is that correct?

Comment: @Paul Michalik Correct, but I'm not using the ViewModelLocator if that is your next question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it depends on you when you want to dispose it. You didn't make that clear. I first thought you meant "When the application closes" then i would use the [exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.exit.aspx) event. But i got irritiated by your statement

> Because if I don't do Cleanup the ViewModel remains in memory and
>   still handles messages. I hope i explained it properly

What can only happen if you want to dispose but your application still needs to run. If your application closes, nothing stays in memory and no messages are handled anymore. But its still good practice to not rely on that.

So if you meant "when the application closes" this is your answer.

Comment: Ok i was worried i didn't explain my need very well. For eg. this Window is some window/control within my appication and i open/use it to do some work using the VM and afterwards i close this window and open another one for some other purpose but with same viewmodel class (different instance) but my VM stays alive because the Messenger class has a reference to it for receiveing messages. what i want/need is an event when my window/control is not in use anymore to call the Cleanup method of my VM. Note Unload event is not good (using tabs and switching between causes Cleanup)

Comment: If its a window you can use the [Closed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closed.aspx) event.

Comment: Yes for window that is fine, what about controls?

Comment: Then you only have the option to use Loaded and Unloaded, but this might be called multiple times, and is not a clear indication that the control is "closed" but thats all there is.

Comment: @dowhilefor Your assuming that everything is managed and will cleaned up for you by the GC and there is an application shutdown taking place. What if you actually have to clean something up manually in this sort of case? What if there is no WPF window as when using an ElementHost?

Answer (score 0):

There's an explanation of why the Messenger still causes a strong reference even when you do an Unregister, and a workaround.

- http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/discussions/235068

Your FrameworkElement ("View") can call the Cleanup in your ViewModel when Unloaded happens:

- [Registering for messages outside of a ViewModel in MVVM Light?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695045/registering-for-messages-outside-of-a-viewmodel-in-mvvm-light)
- [When to dispose ViewModel in MVVM Light](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036873/when-to-dispose-viewmodel-in-mvvm-light)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.unloaded.aspx

Comment: yes I already read that and that's fine, what i'm trying to find is when to call Cleanup on my viewmodel

Comment: thank you but i already tried this approach the Unloaded event and it is good for most of the situations but i need another because Unloaded event happens when window/control is being removed from the visual tree but not necessarily closing. Example are the tab control, switching between tabs causes Unload event and my VM unregisters from messages but this is not my desired behavior cause i want the VM to still be attached to messages until i dispose of my control. Did i managed to explain my issue?

Comment: You could prevent the unloading behaviour when just switching tabs by using a different TabControl. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/212233/Persist-the-Visual-Tree-when-switching-tabs-in-the   and other workarounds    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238072/tabcontrol-disposes-of-controls-on-inactive-tabs

Comment: @colinsith Thanks for your help, it didn't solve my problem directly but instead it gave me an idea how to resolve my issue thanks again

Comment: @Miran Would you like to share your solution?